# Interpolation of months between two dates and calculating a sum using a fixed value for each month

Tags: google-sheets

In a spreadsheet I have a resource estimation for each project with the start and end dates. Every row holds a separate project. Similar to what's below:

[image]

I would like to interpolate the months between Start and end Go Live date and use the same effort for each month. Ultimately, I would like to use this in a pivot table to sum up the monthly totals. It would like similar to below (calculations done quickly by hand so please excuse errors):

[image]

I'd prefer to use any out of the box functionality but if necessary I can also code this. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this task.

You may use 3 formulas, look at the screenshot:

[image]

Here's the formula #1 to make unique list of Regions, it's in cell H2:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

The formula #2 gives the list of dates, it's in cell I1:

```
=ArrayFormula(
EOMONTH(MIN(D2:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,DATEDIF(MIN(D2:D),max(E2:E),"M")+1))-2)+1
)
```

And the formula #3 counts sums, it's in cell I2 and must be copied right and down:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($F:$F,$D:$D<=I$1,$E:$E>=I$1,$A:$A=$H2)),0)
```

Comment: This is good stuff. I haven't been able to get back to this in a while hence the delay for accepting. It mostly does what I need and I can live with it. Thanks!